# Nginx -- Further configuration required

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm a complete nginx noob, so I apologize in advance for whatever necessary details I'm leaving out of this question.

I've got my server set up, and my localhost is displaying the "Welcome to nginx!" page, when I've set my nginx.conf file root to my desired path (which is not the nginx welcome page).

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  0.0.0.0;

        location ~ /devices/(.+) {
            include fastcgi_params;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1;
        }

        location ~ /surveyapp/(.+) {
            include fastcgi_params;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1;
        }

        location / {
            root                    /Users/ryanyoung/Desktop/website/public;
            index                   index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files               $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            error_page              405 =200 $uri;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
            include                 /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index           index.php;
            fastcgi_param           DOCUMENT_ROOT    /Users/ryanyoung/Desktop/website/public;
            fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME  /Users/ryanyoung/Desktop/website/public/index.php;
            fastcgi_param           REQUEST_URI      $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param           QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param           REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param           CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param           CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
            fastcgi_param           CI_URI_PROTOCOL  "REQUEST_URI";
            fastcgi_pass            unix:/usr/local/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_buffers         16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size     32k;
            fastcgi_read_timeout    1800;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Since my root path is definitely correct, my only guess is this has something to do with fastcgi_params? This file is nowhere to be found, and the above path that is referenced (/usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params) does not exist.

I used homebrew to install nginx, so its location is /opt/homebrew/bin. that directory holds nginx and nginx.conf, but no fastcgi_params (and also no fcgi.conf). I've tried every other path I could think of, and I'm fairly certain that fastcgi doesn't exist on my machine.

Not even sure if that's the issue. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Is this the only `server` block in your configuration? I notice that you have `include servers/*;` at the bottom of this file.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! That did help me find that particular issue. It's been almost two weeks and I'm still trying to get this set up.